# Xcode: how do I debug pause in a view/viewController's context while debugging?

Tags: ios, xcode

Sometimes I need to debug pause in a view/viewController context, so that I can get use `self` as the view/viewController object.

Currently, I can achieve this by set a repeatable timer when the view/viewController is created, and when I need to pause the process, I enable a breakpoint in the timer call back method.

This way is fine, but I don't think it's elegant enough, is there a better way to do this?